# How does Ansible module return fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I write Ansible module my_module that need to set some facts.

I define in module the below code

```
.... 
response = {
    "hello": "world",
    "ansible_facts" : {
        "my_data": "xjfdks"
    }
}
module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=response)
```

Now in playbook after execution my_module I want access to new facts, but it's not define

```
- my_module
- debug: msg="My new fact {{ my_data }}"
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Not familiar with `ansible` but considering the `response` object structure shouldn't it be something in the spirit of `{{ ansible_facts.my_data }}`?

Comment: no, I get this error  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'ansible_facts' is undefined"}

Answer (score 4):

You should set `ansible_facts` directly in module's output, not inside `meta`.

To return all `response`'s keys from your example:

`module.exit_json(changed=False, **response)`

Or only for ansible_facts:

`module.exit_json(changed=False, ansible_facts=response['ansible_facts'])`